# Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, lista, interface

Qual a diferença entre `ICollection`, `IList` e `List`?

Quando devo usar cada um especificamente?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As duas primeiras são interfaces. A última é uma implementação concreta. Existe aí uma hierarquia. O tipo [`List`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) implementa uma [`IList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que por sua vez implementa uma [`ICollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). É interessante citar ainda a [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que é implementada pela `ICollection`.

- A `IEnumerable` permite enumerar itens.

  ```
    public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable {
        new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    }
  ```
- A `ICollection` permite contar quantos itens existem na enumeração, adicionar, remover itens no fim da coleção, verificar a existência, entre outras operações.

  ```
    public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
        int Count { get; }
        bool IsReadOnly { get; }
        void Add(T item);
        void Clear();
        bool Contains(T item); 
        void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex);
        bool Remove(T item);
    }
  ```
- A `IList` permite ainda inserir e remover itens em qualquer posição e buscar itens por índice.

  ```
    public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T> {
        T this[int index] { get; set; }
        int IndexOf(T item);
        void Insert(int index, T item);
        void RemoveAt(int index);
    }
  ```

Pelo menos elas indicam que existem métodos que permitem fazer estas operações. Claro que a implementação correta destes métodos na classe concreta é que garantirá que tudo funcione como o esperado.

Obviamente as interfaces não permitem realizar nenhuma operação com elas puramente, você precisa do tipo concreto que no caso é o `List`.

As interfaces são usadas para generalizar o tipo de uma variável, parâmetro ou retorna de um método. E isto é importante para aproveitar código e facilitar a manutenção. Sempre que possível deve-se optar pelo tipo mais geral possível, pela interface.

```
List<string> listaC = new List<string>();
IList<string> lista = new List<string>();
ICollection<string> colecao = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<string> enumeracao = new List<string>();
```

Note que todas variáveis implementam a classe `List`. Mas as variáveis que usam interface podem ter seu conteúdo substituído por objetos de outros tipos concretos ou não sem problema algum, desde que estes tipos também implementem a interface que a variável foi declarada. Por exemplo, a variável `colecao` poderia trocar seu conteúdo por uma [`LinkedList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que também implementa uma `ICollection<T>` sem problemas. Ambos os tipos possuem tudo o que o tipo da variável foi declarado. Exemplo:

```
colecao = new LikedList();
```

Uma coisa importante que além de generalizar o uso quando se usa a interface, é que ela também protege de uso indevido. No exemplo a variável `enumeracao` apesar de implementar uma lista e ter tudo o que uma lista permite, o compilador impede o acesso aos membros que não fazem parte do tipo `IEnumerable<T>`. Ou seja, você não pode chamar o método `Add()`, ou o operador de índice `[]` ou ainda o `Find()`. Concretamente ele está lá, mas como o código disse que a variável é de um tipo superior, o compilador só deixa acessar o que está neste tipo, portanto só pode acessar o `GetEnumerator()`.

```
enumeracao.Reverse(); //gera erro de compilação
colecao[0]; //erro também.
lista.RemoveAt(0); //funciona
listaC.Add("teste"); //funciona, o método está dentro da hierarquia
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Interfaces.cs).

Obviamente se você precisa acessar um `Insert()`, você não pode trabalhar só com um tipo `IEnumerable` ou mesmo `ICollection`. Mas pode usar um `IList` no lugar de usar a lista concreta mesmo. Já o uso do `Sort()` obrigaria ao uso do tipo concreto `List`.

Note que esta generalização pela interface é mais vantajosa quando usada com parâmetros e retorno de métodos.

O assunto é amplo mas a ideia fundamental é essa.

Lembrando que os tipos genéricos são melhores que estes tipos simples que são considerados obsoletos, ou seja é melhor usar: `ICollection<Tipo>`, `IList<Tipo>` e `List<Tipo>`.

[Código fonte de `List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646).

Lembrando que devemos [programar para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Comment: Agora ficou claro. Muito obrigado. Tenha um bom almoço.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, rendeu até um post no meu blog.

Comment: +1 boa resposta.

Comment: Que isso companheiro, uma verdadeira aula! Tomada de decisão já feita após ler isto. Parabéns.

Comment: @Jr.Pacheco obrigado, espero que tenha sido uma boa decisão seja ela qual for :)

Comment: Sempre uso o List quando preciso de uma Lista de objetos de um determinado tipo. No máximo um ADD ou Count etc mais básicas que uso. Mas a partir de agora irei sempre usar o ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; } porque tenho mais opções.

Comment: Simples e objetivo! Muito bom cara!