# Array sem limite de tamanho

Tags: c#, .net, array, lista

```
   ClsPessoa[] Pessoa = new ClsPessoa[10];
```

Sou novo em C# e gostaria de uma ajuda. De que maneira posso declarar um *array* de uma classe como no exemplo, sem inserir um limite de tamanho.

Comment: `List<ClsPessoa> Pessoa = new List<ClsPessoa>;`, com o limite de 2.147.483.648 elementos. É muita pessoa!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O *array* tem tamanho fixo, definiu não pode mudar mais. Você tem que usar outro tipo. O mais adequado é um [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) onde `T` é o tipo da lista. Com ela você pode adicionar elementos sob demanda. Dê uma boa lida na documentação e faça perguntas específicas aqui.

Na verdade, na maior parte do tempo deve preferir uma lista. O *array* só deve ser usado quando há um bom motivo para ele.

Como curiosidade o *array* é usado internamente dentro do tipo `List` como implementação concreta. Mas ele gerencia as manipulações necessárias quando o tamanho não é suficiente. Não existe mágica, só abstração.

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
var pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>();
```

ou se quiser reservar 10 posições:

```
var pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>(10);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/InitSize.cs).

[Isto deve te interessar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101).

E por favor, não use `ArrayList` como sugerido em outra resposta. Também evite esse `Cls` é [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101).

Comment: Qual seria então a sintaxe correta para eu chamar o Metodo Add_Pessoa por exemplo? exemplo: pessoas[0].Add_Pessoa(TXT_Nome.Text, Bday.DisplayDate, TXT_Email.Text);

Comment: Isto não faz parte da sua pergunta original, então seria injusto com as outras respostas a minha ter algo a mais que você perguntou no comentário. Então abra outra pergunta, colocando os detalhes da sua sua classe `ClsPessoa`. Eu respondo lá. Assim fica mais organizado também.

Comment: Já ia perguntar do porquê não usar arraylist mas vi que a tag era C# e nao java kkk

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Não sei se acha que este é o motivo para não usar. C# tem `ArrayList` mas ele não é genérico e deve-se preferir usar a versão genérica. Mesmo que não tenha tipo, é melhor fazer um `List<object>`. Há ganho. E acho que o nome era ruim também. A original foi copiada do Java que nomeou de forma infeliz.

Comment: @bigown entendi, na faculdade sempre orientaram a usar o List<> mesmo, como equivalente mais adequado ao ArrayList de java. Pra falar a verdade nem sabia que tinha uma de mesmo nome no C#.

Answer (score 4):

Use a classe [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
List<ClsPessoa> pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList Pessoa = new ArrayList();
```

Obs: deve ser usada a classe System.Array.

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc564861.aspx

Comment: A classe `Array` só tem utilidades para manipular o *array*. A classe `ArrayList` é obsoleta e não deve ser usada.

Comment: @bigown, vi nesse comentário que você diz que ArrayList é obsoleto. Há pouco tempo passei a usar ArrayList e me ajudou bastante, no caso o List<T> seria equivalente ao ArrayList ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias exatamente. O `ArrayList` é problemático.

Comment: @bigown tenho pouco conhecimento do assunto, mas achei mais fácil manipular Array de dados dentro do ArrayList, senão eu teria que criar List<List<T>> entende ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias faça o que é certo, é bem melhor.

Comment: @bigown ok, obrigado.