# É correto prefixar nome de variáveis com seu tipo?

Tags: variáveis, tipagem, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome

É usual/correto utilizar variáveis onde a primeira letra faz referencia a sua tipagem?

Ex.: `string sVariavel;` `int iVariavel;`, etc...

#### EDIT:

O nome disso é [notação húngara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). Isso é uma boa prática? Qual o lado bom e qual o lado ruim dessa utilização?

Comment: Isso existe mas não é comum(ainda bem), tem outras coisas estranhas como prefixar variáveis com `v`, `o` para objetos, `t` tabelas, `c` campos.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as melhores práticas para dar nome as funções](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106061/91)

Comment: Um ótimo livro para ler sobre o assunto seria o "Clean Code" de Robert Cecil Martin. Há um capítulo inteiro a falar sobre os nomes que damos as variáveis. Não vou postar nada porque a resposta dada pelo @bigown resume muito bem uma parte desse capítulo.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isso chama-se [notação húngara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_h%C3%BAngara) (a pergunta original não falava o que era). É correto... se tiver um motivo para fazê-lo. Ou é errado se fizer só porque viu alguém fazendo.

Olhando assim esses tipos básicos não parecem muito danosos.

Em geral não se recomenda fazer assim. É um indicativo de que o nome da variável não está dizendo qual é sua função no código, e provavelmente poderá ter problemas no futuro se precisar trocar o tipo, o tipo não deveria ser importante.

Pelo menos isso vale para linguagens de tipagem estática. Em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica pode ser bastante útil fazer dessa forma. Tenho experiência com isso e ajuda muito detectar problemas, não se perder no que está usando. Hoje ajuda menos porque existem outras ferramentas que auxiliam, mas nem sempre elas estão disponíveis em todos casos.

No caso mostrado onde a tipagem parece ser estática, ou pelo menos pode anotar o tipo, eu não faria isso, é informação redundante.

Curiosamente muita gente faz isso sem perceber em casos menos óbvios, tipo `btnDeletar`. Esse `btn` é notação húngara. Isso ocorre porque a pessoa aprende com exemplos ruins, muitas vezes até na documentação da linguagem, e o programador não questiona porque está fazendo aquilo, só reproduz a receita que passaram pra ele. Aí é muito errado.

Não tem problema algum em dizer que algo é um botão, mas **se for realmente importante** pro nome da variável que indique que é um botão, então faça `BotaoDeletar`. Acredite no nome, descreva ele direito. Se for só para indicar o tipo que é um objeto do tipo `Button`, aí não costuma ser uma boa ideia.

Pense que tem um `chkOpcao` e um dia precisa mudar para `rdoOpcao`. Imagina ter que mudar tudo no código. Pior, imagina mudar o tipo de objeto, mas não mudar o nome. Só desgraça. Fica pior quando a varável tem visibilidade pública.

Já ouviu falar que comentário pode ficar defasado em relação ao código? Esse é o pior tipo de comentário que existe. É mais difícil de atualizá-lo.

Além disso se você não for húngaro (piada, tá?) é mais difícil de ler um código assim (imagine pronunciar).

Mas se souber o que está fazendo, se colocar onde deve, quando é necessário, se ajudar documentar algo da melhor forma e não causar potenciais problemas, aí não tem problema em usar.

Em uma linguagem eu uso sempre (a linguagem tem pouco mais de meia dúzia de tipos e por isso não gera nomes horrendos). Em outras uso nunca. Mas mesmo onde usava, hoje sinto menos necessidade de usar.

Organizando bem o código e tendo as ferramentas certas, dá pra viver sem os húngaros. O seu uso normalmente indica outros problemas no código. Isso é tratar o sintoma e não a doença.

Boa prática é fazer o certo, o que resolve o problema sem causar outros. Não importa o que dizem que é para fazer, importante é entender todas implicações de usar algo e tomar sua própria decisão.

Um dos [artigos mais famosos sobre o assunto](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) do fundador deste site. Há quem discorde.

[Desvantagens citadas na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages) (ironicamente parecem bem redundantes). O artigo todo tem informações relevantes.

Isso não ocorre só com variáveis. Tem casos que a informação é um absurdo de irrelevância.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bem colocado! :)

Comment: O artigo do Joel é muito bom, pena que você não incluiu o argumento dele na sua resposta. Em poucas palavras, a ideia do prefixo da notação húngara é indicar algo que não está no sistema de tipos da linguagem. Exemplos: esta string é segura ou insegura para ser inserida numa página HTML? Este int está em coordenadas de janela ou de página? Este tamanho é em bytes ou em número de elementos? A resposta do TobyMosque fala sobre isso. Com os prefixos, o erro é mais evidente quando (por exemplo) se soma 5 pixels com 30 laranjas: pxLargura + lrjQuantidade.

Comment: @marcus pelo que entendi isso não é prefixar com tipos, que é o que a pergunta fala. A não ser que esteja falando que essas informações sejam tipos, aí não é para fazer. O que o artigo do Joel fala é exatamente o que eu falei, só não dei exemplo.

Answer (score 12):

Este tipo de conversão é conhecida por `Notação Húngara` e foi desenvolvida pelo `Charles Simonyi` e foi utilizada por muitos anos nos projetos internos da `Microsoft`.

Porém os tempo eram outros, naquela época se desenvolvia um pouco mais próximo da linguagem de máquina, então não havia uma forma clara de identificar o tipo funcional da variável.

Quando falo do tipo funcional, não me refiro ao tipo do objeto, como por exemplo `int`, `string`, `date`, etc... Mas sim à algum comportamento, como por exemplo, se é seguro ou não escrever o mesmo na memória. Neste caso `Charles Simonyi` adotava o prefixo `s` para `safe` e `u` para `unsafe`.

O documento completo com a especificação da Notação Húngara pode ser encontrado na MSDN: [`Hungarian Notation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976(v=vs.60).aspx)

Como esta notação era muito utilizada na Microsoft e trazia algumas vantagens, outras pessoas e companhias começaram a utilizar a mesma, porém em algum momento houve uma falha na interpretação da `Hungarian Notation`, bagunçaram a ideia da mesma com a `OO`, e começaram a usar prefixos que identificam o tipo da variável.

Então com isto temos acabamos por ter duas `Hungarian Notation`, a `App` e a `System`, onde a `App Hungarian Notation` seria a definição inicial da mesma.

Agora um ponto muito importante, `Hungarian Notation` nasceu dentro da `Microsoft` para resolver um problema da época, um problema do qual as linguagens modernas não perecem, por isto a própria `Microsoft` não recomenda o uso de `Hungarian Notation` com `C#`.

[`MSDN: General Naming Conventions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Em sistemas mais antigos variáveis com essa nomenclatura são bem comuns, e ate em cursos (faculdade, etc) professores mais antigos ensinam deste jeito.

**Mas não use** essa nomenclatura para nomear variáveis, tabela, objeto, etc.

E de um nome sugestivo a sua variável.