# Existe um limite ou restrição em relação a tamanhos de nomes de variáveis?

Tags: javascript

Quando comecei a programar diziam ser uma boa prática abreviar nomes de variáveis, para encurtar o seu tamanho.

Entretanto, tenho pesquisado e visto recentemente que esse conceito tem mudado. E hoje em muitos tutoriais os exemplos vem com nomes por extenso. Mesmo que isso torne o tamanho da variável maior.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma problema ou restrição em nomear uma variável com um nome grande como:

```
var pistasEmTextoSeparadasPorVirgula
// "Monaco,Singapore,Interlagos"
// "string"
```

Exemplo tirado de:https://www.javascriptmasters.com.br/blog/teoria/clean-code-3-a-importancia-dos-nomes/

Comment: Talvez caia aqui: [É correto prefixar nome de variáveis com seu tipo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/91). Antigamente se abreviava os nomes pela restrição de memória.

Comment: Era exatamente nesse ponto que eu queria chegar. Eu queria descobrir se existe alguma restrição nos tamanhos de nomes, devido a algum limite em memória. Esse link que você passou responde algumas coisas. Mas não chega nesse ponto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente deve haver uma restrição quanto ao tamanho dos nomes das variáveis em `javascript`, não sei lhe dizer qual o valor máximo permitido, mas provavelmente deve ser um número grande, com o qual você não deve se preocupar. Você pode testar o exemplo abaixo (com 200 caracteres) em seu navegador agora mesmo e ver que ele funciona:

```
var fghfhjflkhflkhflshflhflhsfkjshadjfkhasjfhasljfhjsakhfjsadkhfkjsdhjfkhasdkjfhuiqewyruqweyriuyweqoriuhsafuihasdkjhfasjkdhfjashfjlhaslkjfhalskjdfhalsfjshdakjfhajksdlhfjkahsdlkfhlasfhasdjklfhalsjdkfhalkdq = 10;

console.log(fghfhjflkhflkhflshflhflhsfkjshadjfkhasjfhasljfhjsakhfjsadkhfkjsdhjfkhasdkjfhuiqewyruqweyriuyweqoriuhsafuihasdkjhfasjkdhfjashfjlhaslkjfhalskjdfhalsfjshdakjfhajksdlhfjkahsdlkfhlasfhasdjklfhalsjdkfhalkdq);
```

Com relação a como nomear as variáveis, o mais importante é que o nome consiga descrever bem o que a variável representa. Sugiro a leitura do livro `Clean Code` (Código Limpo, em português) de Robert Martin. Vai lhe ajudar bastante nisso e em muitos outros aspectos!

Comment: Não havia pensado em fazer isso. Criei uma variável seguindo seu exemplo, mas um pouco maior com 151800 caracteres :o! e rodou perfeitamente. Bom agora fica claro que de longe não devo me preocupar com isso. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Opa, por nada! Que bom que consegui ajudar!
"um pouco maior" hahahahahaha

Answer (score 3):

[A especificação não determina um limite](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-identifier-names), então a decisão final fica a cargo de cada implementação da linguagem. Naturalmente tem que haver limites, pois os computadores são limitados em termos de memória etc., mas para fins práticos pode considerar ilimitado.

Isso não quer dizer que seja recomendado criar nomes de variáveis muito grandes. Mas o limite é um pouco subjetivo, a ideia é que o nome seja o mais curto possível que consiga comunicar a função da variável no contexto do seu código.

Comment: Além disso, se não estiver em uma IDE/Editor de texto bom, ficar copiando e colando, ou na pior das hipóteses digitar manualmente, fica cansativo/chato e até inviável para manutenções.

Comment: Sim. Um exemplo disso é programar um app com Android Studio. Os nomes de métodos são enormes. Eu jamais decoraria todos. Mas ao digitar a primeira letra a IDE ja sugere várias opções que começam por ela e vai filtrando conforme você digita. Mas eu ainda prefiro usar nomes maiores do que aquelas abreviações que só que criou sabe o que quer dizer depois.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você desenvolve sozinho, pode criar padrões de abreviatura que para você serão fáceis de decifrar no futuro. Já no caso de trabalhar em equipe, em que outras pessoas precisarão entender seu código, é muito melhor usá-las por extenso, e você ainda pode usar na primeira letra da variável o que ela representa, por exemplo, se for um parâmetro, use pNomeDaVariavel, se for uma variável local use lnomeDaVariavel e assim por diante.

Comment: Eu tenho começado a usar os nomes por extenso. Mas ainda tenho receio e gostaria de saber se existe alguma limite para tamanhos na documentação.

Comment: Não cheguei a testar, mas já fiz essa pergunta pro meu professor de java, e segundo ele, é o limite de uma string, 255 caracteres.

Comment: Seguindo o exemplo do @paulequilibrio. Fiz um teste com uma string de 151800 e rodou perfeitamente! :)

Comment: Sua resposta me lembrou disso: http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Nmes_de_vars_abrv_cm_pouc_vgs

Comment: @alan Até hoje só aconteceu uma vez de eu precisar de um nome maior do que a linguagem me permitia, numa linguagem chamada "Formula", com a qual você provavelmente nunca precisará trabalhar (espero). Escreva seu código do jeito mais claro possível e não se preocupe com esse tipo de coisa. O tamanho do script é, sim, uma preocupação válida, mas, pra resolver isso, é só colocar um "minificador" no fim do seu processo de construção.

Comment: Não vejo vantagem nesses prefixos para identificar um parâmetro e identificar uma variável local. Na verdade, desgosto de 95% das notações húngaras, além de sujar o domínio, em caso de troca de tipos isso prejudica a refatoração. A única notação húngara que eu uso é a para identificar expressão regular (reXpto).

Comment: blz @Pablo Almeida! Valeu! ;)