# O que é Notação Húngara?

Tags: terminologia

Estava lendo um artigo sobre desenvolvimento e o mesmo falava sobre essa tal notação. Gostaria de saber a definição e se é importante utilizar a mesma no desenvolvimento de programas.

Comment: interessante, não conhecia. Vou pesquisar mais mas achei legal a explicação do wikipedia (https://goo.gl/2gY5rv)

Comment: [É correto prefixar nome de variáveis com seu tipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/91)

Comment: @rray pode alterar o titulo da outra? procurei aqui no site e nunca iria encontrar assim

Comment: Antes desta ser postada era o primeiro resultado quando se procura pelo termo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o+h%C3%BAngara

Comment: @bigown talvez tenha sido a forma que busquei não digitei só notação húngara e sim o termo todo igual fiz na pergunta, obrigado :D