# Qual é o melhor método para acessar um membro de uma classe?

Tags: c++, classes, desempenho, métodos-estáticos

Qual é o melhor método para acessar um membro de uma classe no quesito de velocidade e organização?

```
class cMinhaClasse
{
public:
    void Funcao(int r);
};

int main()
{
    // Método 1 - Acessando classe por ponteiro
    cMinhaClasse *mClasse = new cMinhaClasse();

    if(!mClasse)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Erro ao criar o ponteiro para classe     MinhaClasse", "Fatal erro!", NULL); 
    }
    else
    {
        mClasse->Funcao(50);
    }

    // Método 2 - Acessando diretamente
    cMinhaClasse::Funcao(50);

    // Método 3 - Acessando por objeto
    cMinhaClasse MinhaClasse;
    MinhaClasse.Funcao(50);
}
```

Comment: Isso não é c++?

Comment: Sim é c++, postei na area errada?

Comment: Ms-access não é c++. Vou ajeitar as tags

Comment: Desculpe, na verdade coloquei access(para indicar acesso a classes) não sei por qual motivo acabou saindo como Ms-access

Comment: Defina velocidade e organização. Explique o que quer saber.

Comment: O que eu queria dizer quando escrevi velocidade é mais ou menos assim: quando eu acessar uma função geralmente demora um tempo para o compilador executar a função, dentro de uma classe acredito que demore uns milisegundos a mais para ela ser executada, qual é o método de acesso de classe que deixa o programa com um melhor desempenho? O que eu tentei dizer com organização é por exemplo: Para utilizar uma classe diretamente com o :: é bem estranho pois para quem não criou o código a primeira sensação que tem é que isso é uma namespace não uma classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada um faz uma coisa diferente então a comparação fica complicada. A melhor é aquela que te atende na necessidade específica daquele momento.

> cMinhaClasse *mClasse = new cMinhaClasse();

Aqui está criando um objeto no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e atribuindo um ponteiro para este objeto na variável. O tempo de via pode ser longo e geralmente você tem que gerenciar sua destruição se a classe já não o faz. Pode usar um ponteiro inteligente para fazer isto, mas não foi usado neste caso. Se não liberar essa memória haverá vazamento. Só deve ser usado se precisar, o que não parece ser o caso aqui, mas este o exemplo não serve para nada mesmo, então ele não conta.

> cMinhaClasse::Funcao(50);

Aqui está chamando uma função estática, não cria um objeto, se ela não depende de objeto algum pode ser uma boa. Criar um objeto para fazer algo que não precisava dele não faz sentido. Parece ser o caso, então eu diria que neste exemplo restrito é a melhor opção. Mas se mudar um pouco e em casos reais será bem diferente, esta opção pode não ser viável.

> cMinhaClasse MinhaClasse;

Aqui está criando o objeto direto no *stack* e o gerenciamento da memória é automático, mas o tempo de vida é só enquanto estiver dentro da função onde o objeto foi criado. Novamente está criando um objeto sem necessidade no que foi descrito.

Compiladores não executam nada (tem exceção em C++, mas isso não precisa ser considerado para entendimento aqui), eles processam um texto e geral um código de execução.

O tempo de execução destas coisas estão na casa dos nanossegundos e não milissegundos.

É claro que criar um objeto é muito mais demorado, mas se precisa não tem como escapar. Se não precisa não faz sentido algum criar. Como no *link* acima descreve, na *stack* é mais rápido que no *heap*, mas nada supera criar nada.

O que dá desempenho mesmo é fazer algoritmos corretos, entender todo o funcionamento do código em cada mínimo detalhe. Saber um detalhe e não saber os outros, todas implicações, como as características interagem entre si, dificultará bem obter desempenho. Na verdade a busca por ele desta forma não é um caminho bom.

Sintaxe estranha ou não é uma questão de gosto e nada interfere em organização. Por exemplo, para meu gosto esse código é mal escrito e estranho, mas tem quem não ache.

Importa pouco se é *namespace* ou classe em funções soltas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, sobre a parte "Por exemplo, para meu gosto este código é mal escrito e estranho. Mas tem quem não ache." poderia me dar um pequeno exemplo de como pra você seria um código limpo?

Comment: Por exemplo você usa isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foobar
{
    public:

        Foobar( void ) {};
        virtual ~Foobar( void ) {};

        void xpto( int n ) {};
        static void xyz( int n ) {};
};


int main()
{
    Foobar::xyz(50);  // OK: Acessando método estático da classe, não é necessario uma instancia.

    Foobar::xpto(50); // ERRO: Método não estático, é necessário uma instância.

    Foobar * p = new Foobar();   // Instancia do objeto no "heap" - Mais lento e mais complexo gerenciar
    p->xpto(50);                 
    delete p;                    // Instancias de objetos no "heap" precisam ser desalocadas


    Foobar f;        // RECOMENDADO: Instancia do objeto no "stack" - Mais rapido e mais facil gerenciar
    f.xpto(50);
}
```