# Struct de apontador

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Tendo em vista as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct celEstado *apontadorEstado;

typedef struct{

    char nome[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    int qtdCidades;
    float idh;
    apontadorEstado proxEstado;
    apontadorCidade Arv;

}celEstado;
```

Queria tirar uma dúvida sobre o `apontadorEstado`.

Quando eu escrevi a estrutura, eu tinha em mente que estava criando um struct de apontador que recebia o endereço de uma célula estado, mas agora estou com dúvida, pois sempre que uso uma variável do tipo `apontadorEstado` o compilador emite *warning* pois, segundo ele, estou usando um tipo de ponteiro incompatível com o tipo `struct celEstado`. Em contra partida, tenho que por um ponteiro para o próximo estado da lista, e não consigo declarar o mesmo na forma de `celEstado *proxEstado` pois o compilador não permite, então a forma que encontrei de fazer isso foi com o `apontadorEstado`

Exemplificando o erro:

```
int main(){

    celEstado newEstado; //instância da _struct_ celEstado
    apontadorEstado aux; //Auxiliar do tipo apontadorEstado(Ponteiro)

    strcpy(newEstado.nome, "Bahia"); //inserindo o nome do estado
    aux = newEstado.proxEstado; // aux recebendo o endereço do próximo estado
    aux = (celEstado*)malloc(sizeof(celEstado));//alocando a memória pra uma célula estado
    strcpy(aux->nome, "Amazon");//o erro está aqui

    printf("%c", newEstado.nome[0]);//imprimindo o primeiro caractere
    printf("%c", aux->nome[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Erro impresso:

> main.c:25:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'apontadorEstado >{aka struct celEstado}'
>      strcpy(aux->nome, "Amazon");

*Warning* do ponteiro:

> main.c:24:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible->pointer-types]
>       aux = (celEstado*)malloc(sizeof(celEstado));

Objetivamente:

- Estou enganado quanto ao significado do `apontadorEstado`?
- Caso não esteja, por que o compilador acusa erro?
- Como declarar um ponteiro para o próximo estado corretamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Estou enganado quanto ao significado do apontadorEstado?

Sim, mas nem sei dizer exatamente no que porque isto não está bem claro na pergunta. Vamos entender que o que está criando é um ponteiro de `struct` e e não o contrário. E o nome da variável usa [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101) que não costuma ser recomendado.

> Caso não esteja, porque o compilador acusa erro?

Mas está, e não sei bem porque o compilador acusa erro já que boa parte do que está no parágrafo maior não posso responder porque não sei como foi usado, não tem contexto, não tem qual o erro, não tem um código mostrando isto.

> Como declarar um ponteiro para o próximo estado corretamente?

Depende do que quer fazer, mas no [meu código](https://ideone.com/KD1lmX) não deu erro algum, então a forma de fazer isto é como fez.

Com a edição parece que deseja fazer isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Estado CelEstado;

typedef struct estado {
    char nome[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    int qtdCidades;
    float idh;
    CelEstado *proxEstado;
} Estado;

int main() {
    Estado newEstado; //instância da _struct_ celEstado
    strcpy(newEstado.nome, "Bahia"); //inserindo o nome do estado
    Estado *aux = malloc(sizeof(Estado));//alocando a memória pra uma célula estado
    strcpy(aux->nome, "Amazon");//o erro está aqui
    printf("%c", newEstado.nome[0]);//imprimindo o primeiro caractere
    printf("%c", aux->nome[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MdEfj6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TypeDefPointer2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/TypedefPointer2.c).

Vou esperar confirmar para completar, mas note que simplifiquei tirando códigos desnecessários.

Você precisa ter um tipo incompleto declarado antes para poder usar dentro da estrutura, mas ele não deve ser um ponteiro porque você ainda não tem toda informação necessário, o ponteiro só poderia ser criado depois da estrutura já definida que tem tudo o que ele precisa. E aí obviamente não poderia usar dentro da `struct` porque ele ainda não foi definido neste momento.

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de código, editei a pergunta com o código aplicado e com o erro impresso

Comment: Sim, é isso que quero, pois preciso fazer uma lista encadeada de estados Brasileiros, cada um com um ponteiro para uma árvore de cidades que pertencem a ele. Aí estou quebrando a cabeça com a função que vai ler os arquivos com as informações e, posteriormente, armazena-las nas células.

Answer (score 3):

ATUALIZAÇÃO

O erro está nesta linha:

```
typedef struct celEstado *apontadorEstado;
```

e a causa do erro é o fato de que "celEstado" no seu programa não é uma struct, mas sim um **typedef para uma struct sem nome** que você declarou assim

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} celEstado;
```

portanto você não pode usar "typedef **struct** celEstado *apontadorEstado;" como você fez.

Uma maneira de corrigir o erro de compilação sem mexer muito no programa é escrever assim:

```
typedef struct CelEstado *apontadorEstado; // <--- CelEstado C maiusculo
typedef struct CelEstado  // incluido o nome da estruta em maiusculas
{
  ...
} celEstado;
```

Escrevendo da maneira que mostrei em meu exemplo esse problema não acontece.

PS. as postagens de C que vejo aqui normalmente fazem isso, declaram um typedef para um ponteiro de estrutura. Eu acho isso ruim, acho que é menos legível do que usar o ponteiro explicitamente, assim como fiz no meu exemplo.

POSTAGEM ORIGINAL ABAIXO

Sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas eu mudaria a declaração da estrutura para ficar como abaixo, acho que ficaria mais fácil de entender, e você não teria problemas de compilação:

```
typedef struct celEstado CelEstado;
typedef struct celCidade CelCidade;

struct celEstado
{
  char nome[30];
  int populacao;
  int beneficiarios;
  int qtdCidades;
  float idh;

  // apontadorEstado proxEstado;
  CelEstado* pProxEstado;

  // apontadorCidade Arv;
  CelCidade* pCidade;

};
```

Note que a parte referente a "apontadorCidade" eu coloquei por minha conta, para ficar parecida com "apontadorEstado".

PS. o que você chama de "struct de apontador" na verdade é "apontador para struct", ou "apontador para estrutura".

Comment: o problema não é exatamente de compilação, desculpe por não ter sido muito claro, vou reler a pergunta e editar pra melhorar. O problema é quando eu tendo aplicar esse ponteiro  de `apontadorEstado`, fica emitindo o erro de incompatibilidade de tipo de dado

Comment: o erro definitivamente é de compilação...as mensagens que colocou em sua pergunta são mensagens de erro de compilação