# Qual termo usar 'date' ou 'create_at'?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, modelagem

Contextualizando: 

Tenho a seguinte tabela e armazeno a data de criação no atributo `date`.

```
+------------+
| Operation  |
+------------+
| id         |
| amount     |
| type       |
| date       | 
| product_id | 
+------------+
```

Quero saber qual termo se encaixa melhor neste contexto, `date` ou `create_at`?

Comment: na maioria dos bancos de dados `date` é um tipo de dado, e não é bom ter esse nome, o bom mesmo seria nomes diferentes do tipo de dado que possa existir no banco, exemplo como colocado na sua pergunta created, updated, etc ... Então verifique se existi esse tipo de dado no banco se existir não coloque date ...

Comment: Só um comentário, o certo em inglês é `created_at`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende do que você está se referindo.

Se você quer manter uma data de criação para registro então creio que seria conveniente nomear para `create_at` (para manter o padrão adotado).

Agora se "Operação" for uma data de execução, então é conveniente manter como `date`.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade não tem um contexto claro, mas pelo fato que está pensando em `CreateAt` imagino que este seja o contexto e então ele é que deve ser usado, afinal os nomes devem dizer exatamente o que são. Quando usa `date` no fundo está dando o nome da coluna igual ao seu tipo e isto não dá semântica alguma do que ele seja, é o pior uso de [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101), porque o prefixo se tornar a única parte do nome.