# Como adicionar bytes a um byte array?

Tags: c#, byte

Boas.
Como faço para adicionar um byte[] a outro byte[]?

```
Byte1.add(byte2);
```

Dar mais código não vai ajudar em perceber o problema. Mas vou explicar melhor.

Tenho um byte[] chamado fullbytecoll[] que vai guardar todos os bytes[] recolhidos.

Depois tenho um loop que me vai dar sempre vários 'chunks' de bytes[] que pretendo adicionar ao final de fullbytecoll[]. Portanto preciso de uma forma de adicionar data ao meu byte array.

Comment: Precisa ser array? Não é possível mudar o tamanho de arrays. Digo, até é possível, mas envolve um trabalho considerável e provavelmente não é isso que você procura.

Comment: Qual é sua dificuldade? Coloque um código mais completo, informe se está havendo algum problema.

Comment: Adicionei mais informação.

Comment: Realmente não tem como, ou muda pra lista ou reserva espaço suficiente para todos os *bytes*. A alternativa seria criar novos *arrays* conforme precisa de mais espaço, mas é isto que o `List` faz de forma mais correto que a maioria dos programadores fariam manualmente. Isto pode ajudar um pouco entender as operações possíveis de cada coleção: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101

Comment: Ja tentei fazer por lista. e tenho 

listDecomp.Add(DEcompressedB);

e no final do loop, pretendo voltar a passar para byte. Como faco isso?