# Quais são as vantagens do parallel.ForEach em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, loop, paralelismo

Trabalhando com C# eu vi que temos a opção de trabalhar com `parallel.ForEach()`. Qual é a vantagem de trabalhar com ela e não o `foreach`?

Answer (score 10):

O nome dela praticamente entrega tudo o que está sendo perguntado. Desta forma a iteração em uma sequência de itens é avaliada de forma paralela, na medida do possível, e em alguns cenários isto pode aproveitar todo potencial do hardware sendo utilizado. Com a paralelização o processo total pode terminar mais rápido. Ele pode ser aplicado à qualquer objeto que implemente a interface [`IEnumerable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101)).

[Nem sempre a paralelização trará ganhos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). Há um certo risco de fazer um algoritmo que não funcione tão bem em paralelo. É necessário sempre fazer um teste se compensa ou não.

Há problemas que não podem ser quebrados em partes para paralelizar. O exemplo mais típico é quando um resultado depende do resultados anteriores.

A paralelização só compensa onde há vários processadores.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#overloads).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Depende da aplicação.

Se você tem muitos dados para serem processados e a ordem não importar o melhor é o processamento paralelo (Parallel.ForEach()), caso contrário o melhor é o foreach ou outro laço de repetição.

O Parallel.ForEach(), o que ele faz é pegar a sua coleção e dividir em threads e executar o que tiver que ser feito! basicamente é isso.