# Redudancia interface com Disposable

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Vi um exemplo de implementação  de uma `interface` com `Disposable` que julgo ser redundante e gostaria de saber se tenho razão.

Segue exemplo para ilustrar:

```
public interface IClassBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
        void Add(TEntity obj);
        void Dispose();
}
```

A `inteface` acima traz como contrato o método `Dispose`

---

```
public class ClassBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IClassBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    public void Add(TEntity obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Então, `IDisposable` já me obriga a implementar o método `Dispose()` sendo desnecessário adicionar este método na minha `interface IClassBase`, está correto este raciocínio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E quem garante que você vai usar a interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na classe que também vai usar a `IClassBase<TEntity>`? Tendo o `Dispose()` nela é garantido que terá que implementar o método. Se não tiver, passa ser uma opção. Na verdade estou sendo legal em falar em opção. É opção como? A documentação diz para fazer isso? Se for, não garante nada, E nem sei se é função da documentação fazer isso. O fato é que sem garantias em linguagem estaticamente tipada, é um erro conceitual não tê-lo.

Lembre-se que a função da interface é ser um contrato, é pedir que seus implementadores exijam certos métodos. Então ele deve exigir todos. Não pode esperar que uma coincidência faça o que deseja. Se deixar esse método de fora dela está dizendo que ele não importa. Mais ainda, se o acesso for feito pela interface, não poderá chamar o `Dispose()` se ele não estiver listado lá. O tipo protege do acesso à outros membros. Já [respondi sobre isso em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101).

Não que seja proibido, tem motivos para fazer isso, pragmaticamente falando, mas conceitualmente usar uma interface e dizer que o método dela não será implementado significa que a interface não deveria ser usada. Sei que pode ser implementado depois, nenhum problema, mas é bom fazer esse alerta para quem não percebe isso.

Answer (score 3):

No seu exemplo, o recomendado seria que sua **interface** implementasse IDisposable:

```
public interface IClassBase<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity obj);
}
```

Dessa forma você obriga que classes que forem implementar a sua interface, também implementem o IDisposable.

Por outro lado, talvez isso não faça muito sentido, pois IDisposable é *geralmente* implementada por classes que utilizam métodos nativos e que precisam liberar os recursos utilizados manualmente, que não serão liberados pelo Garbage Collecor.

Então o que você precisa saber é: Tem sentido você criar uma interface que obrigue a implementação do Dispose?

Eu geralmente não me importo com isso, deixo pra quem for implementar a minha interface decidir se precisa ou não do IDisposable, e nesse caso, eu implemento o IDisposable diretamente na classe. Lembrando que é recomendado implementar o Dispose em [conjunto com o finalizador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) da classe. Pois o Garbage Collector não chama o Dispose, somente o finalizador da classe.

Lembrando também um outro recurso bastante útil quando uma classe implementa o IDisposable, é a possibilidade de usar o objeto dentro de um bloco [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Garantindo o uso correto do IDisposable chamando o Dispose automaticamente no final mesmo que um erro ocorra.

**UPDATE**:
já que a resposta não está clara, então aqui vai:

Não. Não é redundante. O nome do método é apenas um nome. Como expliquei acima, a interface IDisposable tem essas particularidades, como a possibilidade de usar o bloco using. E como disse, a implementação da interface é mais uma "dica" de que a classe utiliza código nativo que precisa liberar algo manualmente.

Você pode ter o seu próprio método Dispose e pode também implementar o IDisposable.Dispose. Basta implementar a interface de forma explícita:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal interface IMyDisposable
    {
        void Dispose();
    }

    internal class MyDisposable : IMyDisposable, IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose da interface IMyDisposable");
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("método implementando explicitamente Dispose da interface IDisposable");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var m = new MyDisposable())
            {
                m.Dispose();
            }

            //ou então:
            var m2 = new MyDisposable();
            m2.Dispose();
            ((IDisposable)m2).Dispose();

            /*
            print:
            Dispose da interface IMyDisposable
            método implementando explicitamente Dispose da interface IDisposable
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Embora sua resposta esteja correta, ela não faz sentido para o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Explique porquê não, e posso atualizar.

Comment: Onde está dizendo sobre redundância de uso?

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta exatamente sobre "redundancia", mas sim sobre a necessidade ou não de implementar a interface IDisposable. E na minha resposta eu tento explicar um pouco sobre o uso. O fato do método se chamar Dispose não torna exatamente redundante a implementação da interface IDisposable, já que o método criado com esse nome poderia ter qualquer outro.

Comment: A pergunta é muito clara que é sobre redundância. Foi exatamente o que eu disse, você explicou bem outra coisa, não o que foi perguntado. Está no título dizendo que é sobre redundância, fala sobre isso no primeiro parágrafo, e no último onde a pergunta é feita descreve uma redundância.

Comment: ok.............