# Como iterar sobre um dicionário?

Tags: c#, .net, dicionário

Eu já vi várias formas de iterar sobre um dicionário. Existe uma considerada padrão?

Comment: Como a pergunta foi marcada por não estar clara o suficiente, e ninguém se manifestou defendendo o porque, seja informalmente ou citando os documentos da central de ajuda, eu vou solicitar reabertura.

Comment: Na verdade, [algumas pessoas se manifestaram](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5399/18246)

Comment: Para quem quiser votar pelo fechamento, primeiro veja no histórico que ela já foi fechada e reaberta por um moderador. Além disso, ela está sendo debatida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5399/132 - Então, por favor, **não votem para fechar sem apresentar fortes argumentos para tal.**

Comment: @J.Guilherme Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

Sim, existe.

O dicionário e uma estrutura de dados e como qualquer estrutura de dados ela pode ser iterada com qualquer tipo de ciclo. [O msdn dispõe um documento a iterar sobre um colecção de dados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzc4yayd(v=vs.90).aspx), por coincidência essa colecção e um `hashtable` que e o mesmo que um dicionário. O código de la o seguinte

```
Hashtable phones = new Hashtable();
// Alguns adds omitidos por brevidade
phones.Add("Leah", "555-0100");

// Iterar sobre a collecao
System.Console.WriteLine("Name\t\tNumber");
foreach (string name in phones.Keys) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(name +"\t"+ phones[name]);
}
```

Existem outras formas que correspondem a necessidades diferentes.

Antes de continuar com essas formas e necessário perceber que um dicionário pode ser visto como um conjunto de pares (chave, valor). Isto E exactamente o que retornado quando se percorre o dicionário com um iterador.

- Iterar sobre os pares (chave, valor) do dicionário com `foreach`

```
foreach (var pair in dicionario)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

- Iterar sobre os pares (chave, valor) do dicionario com LINQ

```
dicionario.Where(k => k.Key.Contains("ola")).Select(e => new{ ... })
```

- Iterar sobre os valores do dicionario

Qualquer uma das formas acima mas apenas na [propriedade `Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359878(v=vs.110).aspx) do dicionário. Isto e útil se apenas estiver interessado nos valores.

- Iterar sobre as chaves do dicionário

A mesma coisa que `Values`, mas desta vez apenas para as chaves do dicionário. A [propriedade chama-se `Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337739(v=vs.110).aspx)

Existem outras formas de iterar sobre o dicionário, mas estas sao normalmente combinacoes das formas demonstradas acima. Por exemplo, considere o seguinte dicionário

```
var dicionario = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"1", 2},
    {"1.1", 1},
    {"1.2", 0},
    {"2" -1}
};
```

Pode ser interessante obter os valores do dicionario cuja chave comecam com `1`:

```
dicionario.Where(k => k.Key.StartsWith("1"))
```

Outra forma de fazer o mesmo seria:

```
var chaves1 = dicionario.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("1"));
foreach(var chave in chaves1){
    var valor = dicionario[chave];
    //...
}
```

[A comunidade inglesa tem também uma pergunta igual.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

> Eu normalmente costumo dar preferência a primeira abordagem. Do ponto de 
>  vista teórico ela também poderá ser mais eficiente, uma vez que ela tem peso 
>  `O(n * kl)` onde `n` e o numero de entradas do dicionário e o kl e o tamanho 
>  da string que voce está a procura (no meu exemplo é 1).
>  Já a segunda abordagem tem uma operação `O(k)` a mais, onde `k` é o numero de chaves que correspondem ao seu critério.

Comment: e de notar que a [pagina do MSDN do dicionario](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) e tambem referencia para as formas que expliquei

Answer (score 8):

Pode-se dizer que essencialmente só existe uma forma. É a repetição através de um mecanismo de controle de fluxo, preferencialmente estruturada. Não existe um padrão claro, existe o senso comum e as ferramentas mais óbvias. A escolha de uma ou outra forma depende da circunstância.

Os muitos jeitos de usar são quase circunstanciais e tendem ao infinito.

## `foreach`

A forma mais tradicional que vemos na maioria dos códigos escritos em C# e mesmo em outras linguagens é o [`foreach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-inWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O resto são variações dele. A maneira de usá-lo pode variar muito.

```
foreach (var par in dicionario) => WriteLine($"{par.Key} => {par.Value}");
```

Note que cada item a ser iterado é um par de chave e valor representado pelo tipo [`KeyValuePair`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Então o `var` ali pegará este tipo sempre.

Desta forma ele vai do início ao fim do dicionário item por item, sem ordem alguma definida já que dicionários não possuem ordem e vai retornando esse par. Você pode fazer o que quiser com ele, sempre acessando a chave se quiser através do membro do tipo [`Key`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.key?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_2_Key), ou o valor, o mais comum, através do membro [`Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.value?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_2_Value).

Poderia pegar direto a chave ou o valor:

```
foreach (var key in dicionario.Keys) => WriteLine($"{key} => {dicionario[key]}");

foreach (var value in dicionario.Values) => WriteLine($"{value}");
```

Não vou entrar em formas que o dicionário é passado para algum método e esse retorna algo manipulado para o `foreach` lidar já que esta é uma forma indireta. Já deu para notar que há muita variação possível, nem raspei em todas com `foreach`.

## `for`

Não é o mais adequado, mas pode evitar o `foreach`, que apesar de ser uma forma razoavelmente concreta, tem alguma abstração embutida. Tirando essa abstração, um pouco, podemos ter o mesmo resultado com [`for`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/forWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se não souber o que está fazendo ou ter algum descuido, vai dar errado. Tem duas formas básicas:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dicionario.Count; i++) {
    var par = dicionario.ElementAt(i);
    WriteLine($"{par.Key} => {par.Value}");
}
```

Essa forma pode ser usada quando você precisa de um contador junto da iteração do dicionário, mas ela tem um problema porque o `ElementAt()` precisa percorrer o dicionário. Isso provavelmente não é o que deseja.

Se quiser acessar sem esse problema, use o iterador:

```
for (var iterador = dicionario.GetEnumerator(); iterador.MoveNext();) {
    var par = iterador.Current;
    WriteLine($"{par.Key} => {par.Value}");
}
```

Escrevi de forma simples, se fizer assim haverá vazamento de memória, tome isso apenas como um exemplo isolado de demonstração, esse código não está adequado para uso em produção.

Poderia ter uma condição diferente aí no `for` e o `MoveNext()` estar no local do passo (*step*, terceira parte do `for`). Obviamente que tem outras formas de fazer o mesmo.

Simplificadamente essa é a forma como o `foreach` realmente opera.

## `while`

Todo o `for` é praticamente um açúcar sintático para um [`while`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/whileWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Então os dois exemplos acima e diversas outras variações podem ser realizados com essa construção também.

Só deve tomar cuidado porque se tiver um `continue` dentro dele, no primeiro caso o índice não será avaliado e o incremento não acontecerá no `while`, no `for` é garantido que ele ocorra. No caso do iterador não tem problema.

Se quiser garantir que pelo menos uma iteração ocorra pode usar o [`do...while`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/doWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não vou postar muitas variações, só o iterador sem vazamento de memória:

```
using (var iterador = dicionario.GetEnumerator()) {
    while(iterador.MoveNext()) {
        var par = iterador.Current;
        WriteLine($"{par.Key} => {par.Value}");
    }
}
```

## Função recursiva

Todo laço de repetição pode ser escrito como uma função recursiva, talvez com adaptações. [Não acho que iterar um dicionário simples seja caso para uma função recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101), a não ser que o valor fosse composto de dicionários formando uma árvore. Mas é possível fazer isso. Nem vou tentar dar exemplo, considero perda de tempo, mas não está errado.

## `goto`

Claro que todo laço pode ser expressado mais concretamente e menos estruturado com [`goto`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/gotoWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas [não consigo imaginar um motivo para fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101). Nem vou perder tempo.

É uma forma, ainda que não deva ser adequado. Mas se pensar em inadequação, são raros os casos onde o `foreach` simples não seja o mais adequado. Mesmo assim as pessoas usam outras formas.

## Sem laço de repetição

Eu não chamaria isso de iterar. Mas é possível acessar item a item individualmente, usando o índice, `ElementAt(At)` (que haverá um laço embutido), `MoveNext()` do iterador, etc.

## Outras formas

Salvo algum uso bem criativo (algumas bem malucas, mas viáveis e corretas) não consigo imaginar outras variações básicas de construção. Mas se considerar pequenos detalhes diferentes tem sim uma quantidade enorme de variação.

Não vou falar dos casos onde é errado ou pelo menos obsoleto fazer, muito menos dar soluções complexas que não agregam valor.

## Abstração.

O que pode ser feito é criar abstrações em cima destas construções concretas. Pode criar uma função com um [gerador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yieldWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Aí pode consumir essas abstrações. Pode-se então considerar que cada uma dessas abstrações são formas diferentes de iterar sobre o dicionário. Exemplo:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Iterar(Dictionary<string, int> dicionario) {
    foreach (var par in dicionario) yield return par.Value;
}
```

Isso pode ser consumido de várias formas. A iteração ocorre aí, mas você consume ela como o método, nem precisa saber como é feito dentro dele. nesse caso quando usa o `Iterar()` está iterando de uma forma nova.

Imagine que pode iterar de infinitas formas fazendo assim. Mas a base é o laço de repetição que iniciar uma iteração, vai movendo para o próximo item e encerra quando acabar todos os itens ou por alguma condição específica antes de atingir o fim.

#### LINQ

Eu ia fazer um exemplo genérico onde você passa uma *lambda* para o método e ele executa como corpo da iteração. Mas isso é exatamente o que faz a maioria dos métodos do LINQ que veremos abaixo. Ter um método padrão `ForEach()` é outra forma, de fato tem um no LINQ. Ele tem limitações e é confuso para alguns. Muitas vezes ele não faz o que a pessoa espera, a semântica é diferente do uso do bloco normal.

Este tipo de abstração é tão útil que o .NET já possui muitos métodos assim através do [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Há uma quantidade imensa de métodos prontos no .NET para iterar de diversas formas e existem muitos outros em bibliotecas de terceiros. E você pode fazer suas próprias extensões. Tudo o que funciona com [enumeráveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101) funciona com dicionário.

Há extensões semelhantes que podem ser feitas especificamente para dicionários e que não funcionam com outros tipos enumeráveis. Exemplo:

```
dicionario.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => WriteLine($"{key} => {dicionario[key]}"));
```

Recriando a sequência com ordem diferente e filtrando elementos:

```
dicionario.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).Where(kv => kv.Value >= 18)
```

Iterando em paralelo:

```
dicionario.AsParallel().ForAll(par => { WriteLine($"{par.Key} => {par.Value}"); });
```

Imagine quantos exemplos poderia montar usando LINQ.

#### Outras abstrações

É possível derivar a classe [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e fazer interações diversas ali. É possível criar uma abstração em cima do enumerador e evitar o par. Algo assim:

```
public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
   return this.Values.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Dá para pensar em várias outras formas.

Veja funcionando [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aLKLdj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/IterateDictionary.cs).

## Conclusão

Enfim, dá para fazer muita coisa. Não existe uma forma finita de formas de fazer alguma coisa tão complexa, a não ser que queira reduzir ao caso mais concreto, aí é só dizer que precisa fazer um laço varrendo todos itens, e a forma mais concreta de todas que pode ser expressada em C# é usando o `goto` para controlar a repetição.

- É importante entender o conceito do enumerador e do par de chave e valor.
- Se não tiver uma ótima justificativa para fazer diferente, fique com o `foreach` pegando os pares, ou as chaves ou os valores. Se for o caso, faça o filtro prévio.
- Se gostar de abstrações e ver vantagem em algum caso, use o LINQ.
- Se fará alguma iteração específica que usará em muitos casos, crie um método que faça isso de forma mais concreta e use-a onde precisar. No consumo dele para aquele caso poderia usar uma forma mais concreta, mas seria melhor esse método que produz o resultado desejado.

Comment: Eu nao concordo que o for ElementAt seja uma forma aceitavel de percorrer o dicionario. Ele pode ser um algoritmo O(n^2)

Comment: `a forma mais concreta de todas que pode ser expressada em C# é usando o goto para controlar a repetição`. Onde é que existe uma norma a explicar isso? Essa é mesmo a sua experiencia? Se quer mencionar o `goto` pelo menos mencione o `break` tambem

Comment: @BrunoCosta Tinha esquecido de escrever sobre a complexidade, fiz a ressalva na resposta. Até onde eu sei não existe norma sobre uso do `goto`, na verdade nem sei o que quer dizer com isso. Não é minha experiência, é um fato óbvio, se quiser saber sobre o funcionamento de laços e porque o `goto` é mais concreto pode fazer uma pergunta (me avise se for fazer, já vou preparando a resposta), não cabe aqui pelo tamanho e pelo contexto. As outras formas nada mais são que `if` e `goto`. O `break` não tem nada a ver com o `goto` nesse contexto, ele é uma abstração do `goto`.

Comment: Eu sei qual e o funcionamento do `goto`, ao contrario de qualquer outro mecanismo de fluxo ele deixa ir para qualquer ponto de execucao no mesmo metodo... Mas como voce disse ele normalmente leva a codigo espareguete. Ele lembra tambem o velinho assembly... Ficou melhor a respsota.

Comment: Você fala no 2º exemplo do `for` que "se fizer assim haverá vazamento de memória". Isso é por o *Enumerator* implementar *IDisposable*?

Comment: @ramaral em linhas gerais, sim.

Comment: Estive a ver o [código fonte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,741), o método `Dispose()` tem uma "implementação vazia". Assim sendo não há problema em usar o `for` desse modo. Certo?

Comment: @ramaral mas esse é o `Dispose()` do `Dictionary`, que nem implementa `IDisposable`, sei lá porque tem isso aí. O problema é o iterador e não o dicionário.

Comment: Sim, eu estou a falar do iterador. Aquele `Dispose()` é do *IEnumerator* retornado por [getEnumerator()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,578). `IEnumerator<T>` implementa a interface *IDisposable*

Comment: @ramaral é verdade, ele não seguem as próprias recomendações de estilo de codificação :) e me confundiu. Nesse caso parece não haver problemas, mas isso é detalhe de implementação, vai que mude, não pode confiar nisso. O `foreach` chama o `Dispose()`. Não fazer assim pode dar uns *bugs* cabeludos se algo mudar. Por isso que eu falei que quanto mais concreto fizer, mais tem que ter noção de todo o mecanismo e pensar em tudo o que pode dar errado.

Comment: Eu percebi desde logo que aquela sua frase se devia à implementação, por parte do *enumerator*, da interface *IDisposable*. No entanto não via nada que um *Dictionary* tivesse que fosse necessário fazer *"dispose*". O código fonte veio confirmar o que eu pensava. Também não vejo que a implementação possa vir a mudar, nesse sentido.

Answer (score 3):

Segue duas formas que são bastante usadas:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cat", 2},
        {"dog", 1},
        {"llama", 0},
        {"iguana", -1}
    };
    // Loop over pairs with foreach.
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    // Use var keyword to enumerate dictionary.
    foreach (var pair in d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
```

Comment: As duas não são a mesma coisa?

Comment: @jbueno A resposta é sim, são.

Comment: Sim, tem ambas tem o mesmo propósito. Eu uso mais a última pois é mais simples.