# Utilizar IEnumerable ou ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Quero criar um mapeamento 1 x N utilizando a *fluent API* do *Entity Framework*, algo do tipo: um carrinho de compras possui diversos produtos.

Na minha classe carrinho, tenho uma *navigation property*, que é uma coleção de produtos:

```
public class Produto
{
    //Atributos do produto
}

public class Carrinho
{
    //Outros atributos da classe
    public virtual IEnumerable<Produto> Produtos { get; set; } 
}
```

Essa mesma *navigation property* poderia ser modelada como uma `ICollection`:

```
public class Carrinho
{
    //Outros atributos da classe
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; } 
}
```

A minha pergunta é: qual a diferença entre as duas abordagens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usando [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) só poderá enumerar a coleção, ou seja, poderá ler os itens e nada mais além de alterar o valor do item, mas não pode mexer na coleção em si.

Usando [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) poderá modificar a coleção, adicionando e removendo itens.

A documentação (*linkada* acima) mostra quais são os métodos que pode usar em cada uma. Obviamente que usando `ICollection` poderá acessar tudo o que está disponível em `IEnumerable` já que a primeira descende da última.

Se não pretende modificar nada não use `ICollection` é uma forma protetiva para não fazer besteira.

Isso pode ser visto em mais detalhes em [Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: imaginando que ele implementa o IEnumerabe...ele pode remover algum produto (completo) ou adicionar?

Comment: @ihavenokia não sei se entendi o que quer dizer, mas se for o que eu pensei não pode, não há um método em `IEnumerable` que permita isto.