# Qual a diferença ente arrays vs. collections em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, array, estrutura-de-dados, collection

Referente a *arrays* e *collections* em C#, variam de aplicação para aplicação ou existe uma unanimidade entre eles?

Comment: classe [Array](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2) e interface [ICollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se existisse unanimidade não precisaria existir os dois. A dicotomia entre esses dois nem faz muito sentido.

Ao contrário do que as pessoas podem achar, uma coleção que está falando deve ser do tipo `ICollection`, e é algo abstrato, não existe de fato. Você usa uma coleção em específico, e existem várias, assim você deve escolher qual é mais adequada para você para cada situação. Não existe solução única, cada estrutura de dados (e este é o assunto que deve estudar) tem vantagens e desvantagens. Despende da sua aplicação naquele momento o que escolher.

De forma geral nunca deve usar *array* em C#. Ele é concreto demais, tem limitações e quase nenhuma vantagem relevante. Quase todas as estruturas de dados que implementam `ICollection` tem todas vantagens relevantes do *array* e mais algumas. O uso de *array* em código moderno e bem escrito só deveria usar *array* por causa de código legado ou que tenha alguma questão de performance específica.

Tipos que são coleções costumam ter a mesma estrutura básica do *array*, inclusive internamente tem um *array* em muitas delas, mas tem a vantagem de poder fazer algumas operações que *array* não conseguem, por exemplo aumentar ou reduzir o tamanho da coleção. Pode ver mais sobre isso em [Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101). Lendo aí, uma coleção não garante que possa inserir ou remover itens no meio da coleção, apenas uma lista (`IList`) permite isto. Ok, ela é uma coleção também, mas existem coleções que não possuem esta característica.

Uma coleção pode ou não definir tipos nelas, mas as que não permitem são consideradas obsoletas e para todos os efeitos não devem ser usadas, esquece que elas existem, são problemáticas. Mesmo que queira colocar qualquer tipo na coleção moderna e eficiente use o tipo `object`. E mesmo neste caso pense bem se é isto mesmo que quer, quase sempre é um erro fazer assim. E pode fazer com *array* também, só usar `object[]`.

Também não faz o menor sentido o que a outra resposta (havia uma, e foi apagada, a maioria desta resposta é contestação do que havia errado na outra) diz sobre os elementos serem somente de leitura ou não. Em laços brutos em qualquer caso que a estrutura não seja explicitamente *readonly* tanto *array* quanto as coleções podem ter seus dados alterados normalmente, já em laços `foreach` há limitações em ambos por um conta do iterador.

Também estava errado que um deles é definido em tempo de compilação e outro em execução. São iguais, ambos são escritos e definidos em tempo de compilação e ambos são instanciados em tempo de execução, a diferença é só como cada um pode ser manipulado, nada mais, inclusive porque boa parte das coleções tem um *array* instanciado internamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Arrays são estruturas de dados simples e eficientes para armazenar um conjunto fixo de elementos do mesmo tipo. Eles têm um tamanho fixo e são ideais quando você sabe exatamente quantos elementos precisa armazenar e não precisa adicionar ou remover elementos com frequência.

Por outro lado, as collections em C# (como List, Dictionary, HashSet, etc.) fornecem estruturas de dados mais flexíveis e dinâmicas. Elas são úteis quando você precisa lidar com conjuntos de elementos que podem crescer ou diminuir ao longo do tempo. Collections oferecem métodos convenientes para adicionar, remover e manipular elementos de forma mais fácil do que os arrays.

A escolha entre arrays e collections dependerá das necessidades do seu aplicativo. Se você precisa de uma estrutura de dados simples e sabe o tamanho exato do conjunto de elementos, um array pode ser a melhor escolha devido à sua eficiência. No entanto, se você precisa de flexibilidade para lidar com conjuntos dinâmicos de elementos, as collections são mais apropriadas.

Além disso, as collections em C# geralmente oferecem recursos adicionais, como pesquisa eficiente, ordenação e outros métodos úteis, que podem ser valiosos em muitos cenários de aplicativos. Portanto, é importante avaliar os requisitos específicos do seu projeto antes de decidir entre arrays e collections.

Comment: Se o Autor da Pergunta quisesse usar o ChatGPT ele iria direto ao site da OpenIA. [O Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842/137387)  . https://imgur.com/a/OtRBCw0