# Diferença entre ArrayList e MutableList em Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

ArrayList é uma lista mutável e MutableList também é, mas qual a diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`MutableList`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) é uma **interface**.

[**`ArrayList`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) é um **tipo** que **implementa** a interface `MutableList`.

Ou seja, `MutableList` apenas define contratos, define **o que deve ser feito**. Já `ArrayList` implementa **o que deve ser feito**, de acordo com a especificação (contrato) de `MutableList`.

Alguns posts que falam mais sobre isto:

- [Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76316) - Pergunta análoga, para C#
- [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3603)
- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2913)
- [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/18246)

Answer (score 2):

MutableList é um tipo de Lista Generico, ja ArrayList é um tipo mais especifico...

Quando você cria uma `MutableList` você diz que não se importa com o tipo de implementação da lista, ja na `ArrayList` você diz que quer especificamente uma ArrayList mesmo.